# React Transition Group: What is the purpose of TransitionGroup?

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

I'm looking to use the [React Transition Group](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition-group) library to animate some stuff in my React page. According to those docs, the TransitionGroup component does the following:

> The <TransitionGroup> component manages a set of transition components
> ( and <CSSTransition>) in a list. Like with the transition
> components, <TransitionGroup> is a state machine for managing the
> mounting and unmounting of components over time.
>
> Consider the example below. As items are removed or added to the
> TodoList the in prop is toggled automatically by the
> <TransitionGroup>.

I'm not really sure what that means or why it's important.

Also, when I modify the example code that they embed on the documentation page so that the <TransitionGroup> tags are replaced with <ul> tags everything seems to work just fine (I can remove todo items by clicking on them, I can add new todo items).

**Why is <TransitionGroup> component necessary? What does it do?**  (And why do things appear to work just fine when I replace it with an unordered list?)

Answer (score 1):

React Transition Group has some advantages over typical css animations.These are some points that are coming to my mind.

1. Its uses **binding** to change classes for a components. eg: enter, appear, enter-active, appear-active, exit, exit-active etc are all part of animation classes. This make it really interactive interms of rich animations which you can not achive otherwise.
2. It has advatage to **unmount** your component using javascript, once animation is done. So basically no extra load on your front end.
3. It gives your **freedom** to define animations which ever way you like. Either css classes or defineing your own styles with in js file.
4. It gives you various type of animation **options**. Eg: Switch Transitions, Transition Groups, CssTransitions etc.

I would suggest to keep experimenting with typical css animations and react transition group and come to your own conclusion.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer!  I'm looking for info about the TransitionGroup component specifically, but your answer about the overall React Transition Group library overall is solid!

Comment: @MikeTheTall I am in the same boat and trying to understand why exactly is `TransitionGroup` component required? As animations on list can be independently managed by the list component when they are mounting/unmounting. Let me know if you understood its purpose.